# Why Does 2nd Video Play As Black After AVFoundation Merge?

Tags: ios, swift, video, merge, avfoundation

I am using 3 videos in a composition. I can't seem to figure out why the 2nd one plays black after merging them together. It has the correct time and a value when debugging so I know it is there. Here is my code:

```
    import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MobileCoreServices
import CoreMedia
import AssetsLibrary
import MediaPlayer
import Photos

class MergeViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate {

    let clipPicker = UIImagePickerController()
    let audioPicker = MPMediaPickerController()

    var isSelectingAsset: Int!
    // video clip 1
    var firstAsset: AVAsset!
    // video clip 2
    var secondAsset: AVAsset!
    // video clip 3
    var thirdAsset: AVAsset!
    // sound track
    var audioAsset: AVAsset!
    // activity view indicator


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        clipPicker.delegate   = self
        clipPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
        clipPicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie]

        audioPicker.delegate  = self
        audioPicker.prompt    = "Select Audio"

    }

    @IBAction func loadAsset1(sender: AnyObject) {

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary) {

            isSelectingAsset = 1
            self.presentViewController(clipPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }

    @IBAction func loadAsset2(sender: AnyObject) {

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary) {

            isSelectingAsset = 2
            self.presentViewController(clipPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func loadAsset3(sender: AnyObject) {

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary) {

            isSelectingAsset = 3
            self.presentViewController(clipPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }


    }
    @IBAction func loadAudio(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.presentViewController(audioPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func mergeMedia(sender: AnyObject) {

        if firstAsset != nil && secondAsset != nil && thirdAsset != nil {

            // set up container to hold media tracks.
            var mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
            // track times
            let track1to2Time = CMTimeAdd(firstAsset.duration, secondAsset.duration)
            let totalTime = CMTimeAdd(track1to2Time, thirdAsset.duration)
            // create separate video tracks for individual adjustments before merge
            var firstTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo,
                preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
            firstTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, firstAsset.duration),
                ofTrack: firstAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as! AVAssetTrack,
                atTime: kCMTimeZero,
                error: nil)

            var secondTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo,
                preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
            secondTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, secondAsset.duration),
                ofTrack: secondAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as! AVAssetTrack,
                atTime: firstAsset.duration,
                error: nil)

            var thirdTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo,
                preferredTrackID: Int32(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
            thirdTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, thirdAsset.duration),
                ofTrack: thirdAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as! AVAssetTrack,
                atTime: track1to2Time,
                error: nil)

            // Set up an overall instructions array
            var mainInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
            mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, totalTime)

            // Create seperate instructions for each track with helper method to correct orientation.
            let firstInstruction = videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(firstTrack, asset: firstAsset)
            // Make sure each track becomes transparent at end for the next one to play.
            firstInstruction.setOpacity(0.0, atTime: firstAsset.duration)
            let secondInstruction = videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(secondTrack, asset: secondAsset)
            secondInstruction.setOpacity(0.0, atTime: secondAsset.duration)
            let thirdInstruction = videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(thirdTrack, asset: thirdAsset)
            // Add individual instructions to main for execution.
            mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [firstInstruction, secondInstruction, thirdInstruction]
            let mainComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
            // Add instruction composition to main composition and set frame rate to 30 per second.
            mainComposition.instructions = [mainInstruction]
            mainComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30)
            mainComposition.renderSize = CGSize(
                width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width,
                height: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height)
            // get audio
            if audioAsset != nil {

                let audioTrack: AVMutableCompositionTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: 0)

                audioTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, totalTime), ofTrack: audioAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)[0] as! AVAssetTrack,
                    atTime: kCMTimeZero,
                    error: nil)
            }
            // get path
            var paths: NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)

            let documentsDirectory: String = paths[0] as! String
            let id = String(arc4random() % 1000)
            let myPathDocs: String = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("mergeVideo-\(id).mov")
            let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: myPathDocs)
            // make exporter
            var exporter = AVAssetExportSession(
                asset: mixComposition,
                presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
            exporter.outputURL = url
            exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
            exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
            exporter.videoComposition = mainComposition
            exporter.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler() {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    self.exportDidFinish(exporter)
                })
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: Image Picker Methods
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        // Get the media type
        let imageType: String = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! String
        let url: NSURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL
        println(imageType)
        // Place movie in queue.
        if isSelectingAsset == 1 {

            println("Success loading 1")
            firstAsset = AVAsset.assetWithURL(url) as! AVAsset

        } else if isSelectingAsset == 2 {
            println("Success loading 2")
            secondAsset = AVAsset.assetWithURL(url) as! AVAsset

        } else if isSelectingAsset == 3 {
            println("Success loading 3")
            thirdAsset = AVAsset.assetWithURL(url) as! AVAsset
        }

        // Dismiss movie selection.
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func mediaPicker(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController!, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection!) {

        let song: NSArray = [mediaItemCollection.items]
        if song.count > 0 {

            var selectedSong: MPMediaItem! = song[0][0] as! MPMediaItem
            let url: NSURL = selectedSong.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as! NSURL
            audioAsset = AVAsset.assetWithURL(url) as! AVAsset
            println("Audio loaded")
        }
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func mediaPickerDidCancel(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController!) {

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: Merge Helper Methods
    func exportDidFinish(session:AVAssetExportSession) {

        assert(session.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed, "Session status not completed")

        if session.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed {

            let outputURL: NSURL = session.outputURL
            let library = ALAssetsLibrary()
            if library.videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(outputURL) {
                library.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputURL, completionBlock: { (assetURL: NSURL!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                        if (error != nil) {

                            let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: "Failed to save video.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                            alert.show()
                        } else {

                            let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Success", message: "Video saved.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                            alert.show()
                        }
                    })
                })
            }
        }
        audioAsset = nil
        firstAsset = nil
        secondAsset = nil
        thirdAsset = nil
    }

    // Identify the correct orientation for the output video based on the input.
    func orientationFromTransform(transform: CGAffineTransform) -> (orientation: UIImageOrientation, isPortrait: Bool) {

        var assetOrientation = UIImageOrientation.Up
        var isPortrait = false
        if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == 1.0 && transform.c == -1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
            assetOrientation = .Right
            isPortrait = true
        } else if transform.a == 0 && transform.b == -1.0 && transform.c == 1.0 && transform.d == 0 {
            assetOrientation = .Left
            isPortrait = true
        } else if transform.a == 1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == 1.0 {
            assetOrientation = .Up
        } else if transform.a == -1.0 && transform.b == 0 && transform.c == 0 && transform.d == -1.0 {
            assetOrientation = .Down
        }
        return (assetOrientation, isPortrait)
    }

    func videoCompositionInstructionForTrack(track: AVCompositionTrack, asset: AVAsset) -> AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction {

        // get the asset tracks current orientation
        let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: track)
        let assetTrack = asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as! AVAssetTrack
        var transform = assetTrack.preferredTransform
        // identify the needed orientation
        let assetInfo = orientationFromTransform(transform)
        // find the size needed to fit the track in the screen for landscape
        var scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.width

        // if it is portrait, get the size to fit the track in the screen and return instruction to scale.
        if assetInfo.isPortrait {

            scaleToFitRatio = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / assetTrack.naturalSize.height
            let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleToFitRatio, scaleToFitRatio)
            instruction.setTransform(CGAffineTransformConcat(assetTrack.preferredTransform, scaleFactor),
                atTime: kCMTimeZero)
        } else {

            // If it is landscape then check for incorrect orientation and correct if needed, then return instructon to re-orient and scale.
            let scaleFactor = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleToFitRatio, scaleToFitRatio)
            var concat = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(assetTrack.preferredTransform, scaleFactor), CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 2))
            if assetInfo.orientation == .Down {
                let fixUpsideDown = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(M_PI))
                let windowBounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
                let yFix = assetTrack.naturalSize.height + windowBounds.height
                let centerFix = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(assetTrack.naturalSize.width, yFix)
                concat = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(fixUpsideDown, centerFix), scaleFactor)
            }
            instruction.setTransform(concat, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you set the opacity of the second track to `0.0` after the first+second track duration instead of what you have now:

```
secondInstruction.setOpacity(0.0, atTime: secondAsset.duration)
```

to:

```
secondInstruction.setOpacity(0.0, atTime: firstAsset.duration+secondAsset.duration) //(Untested, but the idea is there).
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! Fresh knowledgable eyes are amazing. I will try that right now.